# Please help solve my kmap

Tags: karnaugh-map

I've been scratching my head for a few hours over my issue.

[[image: eKamp1]

This is my kmap i am trying to solve and simplify

This is my working soltion

~Q3 & ~Q2 & ~Q1 & Q0 & x & y || ~Q3 & ~Q2 & ~Q1 & Q0 & x & ~y || ~Q3 & ~Q2 & Q1 & ~Q0 & x & y || ~Q3 & ~Q2 & Q1 & ~Q0 & x & ~y || ~Q3 & ~Q2 & Q1 & Q0 & x & y ||
~Q3 & Q2 & ~Q1 & ~Q0 & x & y ||~Q3 & Q2 & ~Q1 & Q0 & x & y || ~Q3 & Q2 & ~Q1 & Q0 & x & ~y || ~Q3 & Q2 & Q1 & ~Q0 & x & y || ~Q3 & Q2 & Q1 & ~Q0 & x & ~y || ~Q3 & Q2 & Q1 & Q0 & x & y ||
Q3 & ~Q2 & ~Q1 & ~Q0 & x & y ||Q3 & ~Q2 & Q1 & ~Q0 & x & y|| Q3 & ~Q2 & Q1 & ~Q0 & x & ~y||

This is my simplified solution that does not work

~Q3 & x | Q2 & x & y |Q1 & ~Q0 & X | Q3 & ~Q1 & ~Q0 & x & y |~Q3 & Q1 & Q0 & x & y

This is a computer generated solver for kmap that works

Q3 & ~ Q2 & ~ Q0 & x & y | ~ Q3 & Q2 & x & y | ~ Q3 & Q1 & ~ Q0 & x | ~ Q3 & Q1 & x & y | ~ Q3 & ~ Q1 & Q0 & x | ~ Q2 & Q1 & ~ Q0 & x;

But i cant see how they got it from my kmap

can someone please shed some light for me and circle the groups they relate too?

Comment: We won't do your homework for you. You need to show us that you have made a substantial effort to solve this yourself and then ask a **specific** question. What you have given us is not a proper Karnaugh map, so you should dig into that. You also need to explain clearly what inputs and outputs your logic block has.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback elliot. turns out my kmap has the 00 01 10 11 in the wrong order and that was giving me the wrong groups. solved now